# How to openlayer feature without scroll-bar

Tags: openlayers

I want to avoid `scroll-bar` for `openlayers popup feature`,following is my code

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
            event.feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
            content,
            null, true, onPopupClose);

event.feature.popup = popup;
map.addPopup(popup);
```

Map `div` size is `250px x 250px`,if `popup` content is more than `map div` then `scroll-bar` is getting, can't we avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the OpenLayers style with custom style, for example:

```
.olPopup {
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
.olPopupContent {
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  max-width: 450px;
}
```

Also have a look at the available popup types as some may suit your needs better than other.

Comment: I've tried above `css` but popup is not showing after this change.Thanks for your support.

Comment: Use FireBug or some browser tool to find out which css you want to change. I do not use a FramedCloud popup so the classes may be different.